# Calculate position by degrees in CSS?

Tags: css, trigonometry

Okay, this question is a bit math, a bit CSS help... Lets say I have a polygon:

```css
:root {
  --poly-height: 100px;
  --poly-width: 300px;
}

.poly1 {
  background-color: black;
  height: var(--poly-height);
  width: var(--poly-width);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    30px 100%,
    100% 100%,
    calc(100% - 20px) 50%,
    100% 0
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="poly1">&nbsp;</div>
```

This polygon has FIVE points, lets call them `A` `B` `C` `D` `E`.

If we look at point `B`, you can see the `x,y` position is `30px 100%`. This leads to a slant of I don't know how many degrees...

Now lets say, some time in the future, I want to change the height of the `.poly1` element. However, changing the height of the element will also change the degrees of the slant since the 30px inset is set in stone.

What I would like to know, is if there is a way to calculate for the value of the inset, knowing the height of the element, the starting point of `0,0`, and a desired degree of slant, lets say 20deg... and can this be done in a CSS calc?

So starting from point `A` of `0,0`, I would like to get the `x` value of point `B`, desiring a 20deg slant, and knowing what the value of `y` is going to be. In the example above, it is set to `100px`;

- EDIT *

Searching online, I have found out that the math calculation for this would be:

```
y = height * tan(20 degrees)
```

Now... is it possible to do this in a CSS3 calc?

Comment: What are you referring to as point B?

Comment: @JefréN. the position marked `30px 100%`... its the bottom left corner of the polygon.

Comment: And you want to calculate the values necessary for point B so that it has a 20 degree slant?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for `calc(math here) 100%`

Comment: I think you're looking for some trigonometry...

Comment: Yes... thats the point of my question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122553/discussion-between-jason-axelrod-and-jefre-n).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS cannot do this on its own with the syntax `tan` you're suggesting. Even pre-processor languages such as Sass/SCSS don't have built-in trigonometric functions.

You definitely need a CSS3 variable (`--polygon-height`) if you want to be able to change it only in one place (or use a pre-processor). You can then use `var()` to get the value of the variable where needed and `calc` to approximate the `tan` value.

## Taylor series

[Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) is some very awesome stuff. This is how computers under the hood probably calculate complex stuff such as trigonometric functions which you need.

Here's how you calculate tangent.

[image: Tangent power series]

Note that the formula uses **radians** and not degrees. Also note that this is an **approximation** and might or might not work for ou depending on the angle size and the precision you desire. Search online for more terms if you need them.

## Implementation

Now we can use `calc` because we just need simple addition and multiplication. We don't have powers so we need to multiply mulitple times.

```css
:root {
  --poly-height: 100px;
  --poly-width: 300px;
  --poly-degree: calc(20 * 0.0174533); /* degree to radian */ 
}

.poly1 {
  background-color: black;
  height: var(--poly-height);
  width: var(--poly-width);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    calc(var(--poly-height) * (var(--poly-degree) + (1/3) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) + (2 / 15) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) + (17/315) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree))) 100%,
    100% 100%,
    calc(100% - 20px) 50%,
    100% 0
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="poly1">&nbsp;</div>
```

## Example

Here's what happens if we change some stuff.

```css
:root {
      --poly-height: 200px;
      --poly-width: 300px;
      --poly-degree: calc(45 * 0.0174533);
    }

    .poly1 {
      background-color: black;
      height: var(--poly-height);
      width: var(--poly-width);
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        calc(var(--poly-height) * (var(--poly-degree) + (1/3) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) + (2 / 15) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) + (17/315) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree) * var(--poly-degree))) 100%,
        100% 100%,
        calc(100% - 20px) 50%,
        100% 0
      );
    }
```

```html
Height: 200px, degree: 45deg
<div class="poly1">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Such a great idea to use Taylor approximation.

Comment: You should now be able to use `sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()` and so on in all three major browsers: https://web.dev/css-trig-functions/